How to add external email notification to SAP workflow WS20000077?
I need to add email notification to WS20000077 workflow in SAP. All approvers should get an email notification when they have an internal approval request in the SAP inbox.
In the container there are only PurchaseRequisition, which is of Object Type BUS2105, and ReleaseCode, which is of the ABAP Dict. Reference T16FC field FRGCO. I could not find anywhere the personal ID or any other information about the approver.
I tried to review what is in the container but could not get any information on the approver.

Workflow notifications (e.g. search the program SWN_SELSEN in the SAP documentation) permit to send emails (and more) for any workflow workitem. It doesn't require a programming knowledge. Now, if you still need the workitem recipients ("selected agents"), they are stored in the table SWWUSERWI when the workitem is created, and cleared after the workitem has been processed.

This step is performed in TS20000159 task. If you look into the container of this task, you'll find the "Agents" table that should contain users assigned to this task.
To achieve your goal you can create a program exit for this step in the workflow:

a class that implements IF_SWF_IFS_WORKITEM_EXIT interface.
in the EVENT_RAISED method check that you are in after_create event.
get agents from container using IM_WORKITEM_CONTEXT->GET_WI_CONTAINER->GET


How to check in EVENT_RAISED that I am in after_create event?

There is a parameter IM_EVENT_NAME in this event. You can compare its equality to IF_SWF_IFS_WORKITEM_EXIT=>C_EVTTYP_AFTER_CREATE.
